# Using mixins as functions

Tags: less

I need to return value form LESS Mixin to less CSS attribute. It is simple in SCSS but unable to replicate it in Less. Anyone who can resolve this issue for me. Thanks in advance. Below is the example what I wanted to achieve form LESS Mixin.

In LESS

```
.rem(@pixel) {
  @em: unit(@pixel*0.025,rem);
}
```

Not able to return this value like in SCSS

In SCSS

```
@function pxtorem($pixels, $context: 0.0625) {
    @return #{$pixels*$context}rem;
}

.div {
    font-size: rem(16);
}
```

output:

```
.div {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Want to return the value like in SCSS

Answer (score 0):

See [Using Mixins as Functions](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixins-as-functions-feature).

I.e. in your case it will be something like:

```css
.pxtorem(@pixels, @context: 1./16) {
    return: 1rem * @pixels * @context;
}

.div {
    font-size: .pxtorem(8)[];
}
```